# How to execute multiple contracts in single groovy test file using Spring Cloud Contract Test framework?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I have more than 2 contract test in same groovy test file. When I am executing the contract test using spring cloud contract test framework on the provider side, it always take the last contract test from the groovy test file and ignore the first one when generating ContractVerifierTest.java file.

Please find below contract test code:

```
package contracts

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    name("contract test 1")
    description "should return status 200 OK"

    request {
       url "/endpoint1"
       method GET()
    }


    response {
       status OK()
       headers {
          contentType applicationJson()
       }
       body (

             sampleValue: '12345'
       )
    }
}

Contract.make {
    name("contract test 2")
    description "should return status 201 OK"

    request {
       url "/endpoint2"
       method PUT()
    }


    response {
       status CREATED()
       headers {
          contentType applicationJson()
       }

    }
}
```

Generated contractVerifierTest.java

Here we can see that we have the last contract test present in this autogenerated file and contract test 1 is ignored.

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.specification.MockMvcRequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.response.ResponseOptions;

import static org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.assertion.SpringCloudContractAssertions.assertThat;
import static org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.util.ContractVerifierUtil.*;
import static com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert.JsonAssertion.assertThatJson;
import static io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc.*;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class ContractVerifierTest extends ContractVerifierBase {

    @Test
    public void validate_contracttest() throws Exception {
        // given:
            MockMvcRequestSpecification request = given();


        // when:
            ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)
                    .get("endpoint2");

        // then:
            assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(201);
            assertThat(response.header("Content-Type")).matches("application/json.*");

    }
```

Build.gradle:

```
contracts {
    contractsDslDir = file("src/contractTest/resources/contracts/")
    packageWithBaseClasses = 'com.contracts'
    baseClassForTests = 'com.contracts.ContractVerifierBase'
    baseClassMappings {
       baseClassMapping(".*com.contracts.*", "com.contracts.ContractVerifierBase")
    }
}

contractTest {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging{
       events "Passed", "Skipped", "Failed"
    }
}
```

ContractVerifierBase.java

```
import com.ServiceApplication;
import com.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.exceptions.SystemIntegrationException;

import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;


@SpringBootTest(classes = ServiceApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public abstract class ContractVerifierBase {



  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() throws SystemIntegrationException, ResourceNotFoundException {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup();

  }
}
```

Tried to have multiple contracts in the same groovy test file but it did not work.

Comment: I got the answer for above question in https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/2.1.x/multi/multi_contract-dsl.html  in section 9.12 Multiple Contracts in One File. Thank you!